# Are offending users notified about serial voting being reversed?

Tags: support, serial-voting

Yesterday I answered a question (within the comments, a bad habit, but the answer was trivial). As a result, it seems that the asker went through some of my posts and gave them serial upvotes.

Today I got the rep reversed which is not a problem to me. But I then instinctively went to tell the suspected user that serial upvoting is not a good idea. But, while typing my comment I realized that

1.) this might not actually be the user who upvoted my posts, and

2.) they might already have been notified.

So my question is: Does the user (whomever they might be) that upvoted my posts serially, get a notification when the system reverses it? Or is there some sense in trying to relay this to them?

Comment: They do not receive an automatic message. They may notice that they regained reputation if they downvoted answers (a voting reversed event in their reputation log), but that's the extend of it. So for serial *upvoting*, the reversal usually goes unnoticed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Hmm. And if the behaviour repeats itself? Does the offending user not get his knuckles rapped at some point?

Comment: @MartijnPieters That settles my doubts. Personally I feel like the offending user _should_ know about this occurring. Since it was an action taken with good intent, it would be nice if there was an article/post that explained why showing appreciation for a user by serially upvoting their posts is not desired. The argument of "upvoting is not about rep, but about marking useful information" seem good to me.

Comment: @DavidPostill: no, no automation currently exists, even in the event of multiple attempts. However, if a user were to evade the automatic reversals and give someone a higher-than-usual number of votes, then they'll receive some attention from a moderator.

Comment: Aside: I was recently thinking of suggesting that serial downvoters are _automatically_ suspended for an increasing amount of time, starting at a day. However I imagine this must already have been thought of, and decided against.

Comment: Aside to the aside: Maybe suspend their voting rights?

Comment: Your entire profile is just, _"Just a reminder:  You have **40** upvotes per day, they are **free**."_  Seems like that may be soliciting the discouraged behavior that's apparently happening to you.

Comment: @Nat I disagree. How is that soliciting discouraged behavior? It simply states to anyone reading that they have 40 upvotes to spend per day.

Comment: @TylerH In another context, e.g. in a comment on Meta, it'd be less strange.  But as the _only_ item in someone's profile?  It looks like a request.  And apparently someone took it that way and complied.

Comment: @Nat I hadn't thought about that, it's a good point. It was meant to encourage users (mostly myself) to upvote beginner's questions that might not be perfect, but still show a good effort. Since it doesn't cost anything, and it encourages them to keep using the site.

Comment: _"I answered a question (within the comments, a bad habit, but the answer was trivial)"_ That doesn't mean the answer was necessarily correct. When you provide an "answer" in the comments section, you bypass the entire peer review system. Please do not do that.

Comment: @Nat: I'm more concerned with the comma splice!

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Like I said, _"...a bad habit"_, which usually comes either from speculating on the answer and turning out to be correct, or being afraid of looking like a "rep-whore" for posting a trivial answer, that probably has a dupe, that I just can't find/don't know about. You are right though.

Comment: reminding users that down votes on crap questions are free would benefit the site and not just you.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson That reminder was never meant to benefit me, like I tried to explain in a later comment. Of course, I experience my own statements within a wealthy context (my entire character). But hearing it again, from someone else, it does sound like begging for upvotes, so I have since removed it.